# Mutating objects referenced by class attributes through instance methods

Tags: python

This is a two-part query, which broadly relates to class attributes referencing mutable and immutable objects, and how these should be dealt with in code design. I have abstracted away the details to provide an example class below.

In this example, the class is designed for two instances which, through an instance method, can access a class attribute that references a mutable object (a list in this case), each can “take” (by mutating the object) elements of this object into their own instance attribute (by mutating the object it references). If one instance “takes” an element of the class attribute, that element is subsequently unavailable to the other instance, which is the effect I wish to achieve. I find this a convenient way of avoiding the use of class methods, but is it bad practice?

Also in this example, there is a class method that reassigns an immutable object (a Boolean value, in this case) to a class attribute based on the state of an instance attribute. I can achieve this by using a class method with cls as the first argument and self as the second argument, but I’m not sure if this is correct. On the other hand, perhaps this is how I should be dealing with the first part of this query?

```
class Foo(object):
    mutable_attr = ['1', '2']
    immutable_attr = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attr = []

    def change_mutable(self):
        self.instance_attr.append(self.mutable_attr[0])
        self.mutable_attr.remove(self.mutable_attr[0])

    @classmethod
    def change_immutable(cls, self):
        if len(self.instance_attr) == 1:
            cls.immutable_attr = True


eggs = Foo()
spam = Foo()
```

Comment: How are you intending to call `change_immutable`?

Comment: e.g. `Foo.change_immutable(eggs)`?

Comment: Can you tell us what is the big picture? Why do you want to have `change_immutable(...)` if it seems that you want your `immutable_attr` to tell you if one of the instances has one element in `instance_attr`?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Perhaps it was a poor example. Consider a game where the length of a player's list attribute beyond a certain level triggers a Boolean class attribute called Game Over that applies to all players. That is essentially what the example refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a class-level attribute (which, as you say, is "visible" to all instances of this class) using a class method like you show is fine.  This is, mostly, a question of style and there are no clear answers here.  So what you show is fine.

I just want to point out that you don't have to use a class method to accomplish your goal.  To accomplish your goal this is also perfectly fine (and in my opinion, more standard):

```
class Foo(object):

    # ... same as it ever was ... 

    def change_immutable(self):
        """If instance has list length of 1, change immutable_attr for all insts."""
        if len(self.instance_attr) == 1:
            type(self).immutable_attr = True
```

Or even:

```
    def change_immutable(self):
        """If instance has list length of 1, change immutable_attr for all insts."""
        if len(self.instance_attr) == 1:
            Foo.immutable_attr = True
```

if that's what you want to do.  The major point being that you are not forced into using a class method to get/set class level attributes.

The `type` builtin function (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) simply returns the class of an instance.  For new style classes (most classes nowadays, ones that ultimately descend from object) type(self) is the same as `self.__class__`, but using type is the more idiomatic way to access an object's type.

You use `type` when you want to write code that gets an object's ultimate type, even if it's subclassed.  This may or may not be what you want to do.  For example, say you have this:

```
class Baz(Foo): 
    pass

bazzer = Baz()
bazzer.change_mutable()
bazzer.change_immutable()
```

Then the code:

```
type(self).immutable_attr = True
```

Changes the `immutable_attr` on the `Baz` class, not the `Foo` class.  That may or may not be what you want -- just be aware that only objects that descend from `Baz` see this.  If you want to make it visible to *all* descendants of `Foo`, then the more appropriate code is:

```
Foo.immutable_attr = True
```

Hope this helps -- this question is a good one but a bit open ended.  Again, major point being you are not forced to use class methods to set/get class attrs -- but not that there's anything wrong with that either :)

Just finally note the way you first wrote it:

```
@classmethod
def change_immutable(cls, self):
    if len(self.instance_attr) == 1:
        cls.immutable_attr = True
```

Is like doing the:

```
type(self).immutable_attr = True
```

way, because the `cls` variable will not necessarily be `Foo` if it's subclassed.  If you for sure want to set it for *all* instances of `Foo`, then just setting the `Foo` class directly:

```
Foo.immutable_attr = True
```

is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I haven't seen this use of the type function before. Would you mind elaborating a bit on what's going on?

Comment: Sure, I'll do my best to elaborate in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibility:

```
class Foo(object):
    __mutable_attr = ['1', '2']
    __immutable_attr = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attr = []

    def change_mutable(self):
        self.instance_attr.append(self.__class__.__mutable_attr.pop(0))
        if len(self.instance_attr) == 1:
            self.__class__.__immutable_attr = True

    @property
    def immutable_attr(self):
        return self.__class__.__immutable_attr
```

So a little bit of explanation:
1. I'm making it harder to access class attributes from the outside to protect them from accidental change by prefixing them with double underscore.
2. I'm doing `pop()` and `append()` in one line.
3. I'm setting the value for `__immutable_attr` immediately after modifying  `__mutable_attr` if the condition is met.
4. I'm exposing `immutable_attr` as read only property to provide easy way to check it's value.
5. I'm using `self.__class__` to access class of the instance - it's more readable than `type(self)` and gives us direct access to attributes with double underscore.